# How do I trigger different events after different time intervals in Processing?

Tags: java, loops, timer, processing, break

I am creating a "mock" interface which "scans" your brain, and I want to show certain visuals, images, videos, sounds etc. at certain points of time in my sketch.

I've tried a number of timer solutions which I've found in multiple forums -- which work if the intervals are constant. But I am confused about how to write multiple conditions as my intervals are not constant and I want multiple media to be displayed at different times.

I was testing it with just text first. This is what I have so far:

```java
int per = 0;
int time;

String headband = "Clip band around your head to begin";
String access = "Welcome to Brain Frame -- an intersection between the mind and the virtual. Please press the blue button to proceed a neural link. Press the red button to exit.";
String Y ="Establishing pre-cursory neural link. Do not remove headband."; 
String N ="Shutting Down. Do not remove headband until prompted - may result in memory distortion otherwise.";

boolean yes = false;
boolean no = false;
boolean head = false;


void setup() {
  size(1080, 720); 
  time = millis();
}

void draw () {
    background(0);

    fill(0,255,255);
    text (headband, 540, 360);
    textSize(30);
    textAlign(CENTER);

    if(head) {
        background(0);
        text(access, 540, 360);
    }

    if(yes)  { 
        background(0);
        text(Y + "\n" + per + "%", 540, 360);

        if (per < 100) {
            per +=1;
        } else {
            per = 100;
            background(0);

            if (millis() - time >= 5000) {
                text("Link created", 540, 360);
                time = millis(); 


                if (millis() - time >= 3000) {
                    background(0);
                    text("think about your childhood", 540, 360);
                    time = millis();
                }
            } 

            if (no) {
                background(0);
                text(N, 540, 360);
            }
        }
    }
}

void keyPressed(){

     if (key == 'j' || key == 'J'){
         head = true;
     }

     if (key == 'y' || key == 'Y'){
         yes = true;
     }

     if (key == 'n' || key == 'N'){
         no = true;
     }
}
```

However it does not work and ends up showing "Link created" flashing on screen every 5 seconds.

Comment: As I see this, there are two ways to proceed: either you count milliseconds, or you count the number of frames. Both have advantages, but it depend what would suit you. I usually consider milliseconds better to keep everything going during a game like loop, but for an animation maybe frames would be better suited? Your call.

Comment: @laancelot If I go forward with the milliseconds route, how should I write the conditions? The code I've posted does not work, it shows a screen with "Link Created" flashing every 5 seconds..

Comment: I am really new to processing, so I really have no idea how I would go about animating through frames..Is there a particular link you could point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're animating text. There are many ways to do this, but in this case I think that using milliseconds to time your animation would do it justice. It could have been the other way around, but with plain text I think the easier for you will be the better.

For a more complicated purpose, I would suggest you to [learn about a design pattern named "States"](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state). Yet, for this animation, we'll ninja our way through it in a way which will be close to what you already did, yet better for your purpose.

We'll use a simple `switch`, with a state-like logic.

A switch is a simple statement which compare a variable to a succession of possible values. As soon as it reaches a value it recognize, it "enters" this case and do whatever is written there.

You can imagine it as a more rudimentary `If ... Else If ... Else` statement. It's not exactly the same, as than one `case` inside the switch can be read as you have to "break" a case to avoid the other ones being run too, but in the end it's quite similar, yet often easier to read.

We'll use the `switch` because it's easy to use, and because it'll be clean for you to read and understand.

A "state" is a way of defining what is currently happening with a specific object (which is your whole animation in the case).

We'll need a new variable to hold the current state. We'll call it "state" I guess. It'll be a string. It could be anything, I guess, but a String will be easy to read for you, and as a wise man once said: code for humans, and as a side-effect computers will be able to read it.

The switch will check what the current state is, and acts accordingly. This way, you'll be able to reset your timer every time you change to a new state. I'm modify your current code to reflect this, and let you do most of the job.

Also, one last thing: to make things easier, I'm giving you this class: Delay. It's something I coded as a student, and I still use it from time to time. It acts as a timer. This class will permit you to set an amount of time and check if it's expired.

```
class Delay {
  protected int limit;

  public Delay() {limit = millis();}
  public Delay (int l) {
    limit = millis() + l;
  }

  public boolean expired () {
    if (millis() > limit) { return true; }

    return false;
  }
}
```

And here's the modified code (including the `Delay` class):

```
int per = 0;
String state = "beginning";
String currentText = "";
Delay delay;

String headband = "Clip band around your head to begin";
String access = "Welcome to Brain Frame -- an intersection between the mind and the virtual. Please press the blue button to proceed a neural link. Press the red button to exit.";
String Y ="Establishing pre-cursory neural link. Do not remove headband."; 
String N ="Shutting Down. Do not remove headband until prompted - may result in memory distortion otherwise.";

boolean yes = false;
boolean no = false;
boolean head = false;

class Delay {
  protected int limit;

  public Delay() {limit = millis();}
  public Delay (int l) {
    limit = millis() + l;
  }

  public boolean expired () {
    if (millis() > limit) { return true; }

    return false;
  }
}

void setup() {
  size(1080, 720); 
  delay = new Delay();
}

void draw () {
  SetText();


  background(0);

  fill(0,255,255);
  text (currentText, 540, 360);
  textSize(30);
  textAlign(CENTER);
}

void SetText() {
  // This method will check what text you should display and set it. The draw() method will... well, just "draw" everything.

  // The switch "choose" what to do by checking what you set the "state" variable to.
  switch(state) {
    case "beginning":
      currentText = headband;
      if (head) {
        state = "head";
      }
      break;
    case "head":
      currentText = access;
      if (yes) {
        state = "yes";
      } else if (no) {
        state = "no"; 
      }
      break;
    case "yes":
      currentText = Y + "\n" + per + "%";
      if (per < 100) {
        if (delay.expired()) {
          // the delay timer will expire every 100 milliseconds until the 'per' variable is 100, kinda like you did but with a timer
          per += 1;
          delay = new Delay(100);
        }
      } else {
        state = "childhood";
        delay = new Delay(3000);
      }
      break;
    case "no":
      currentText = N;
      break;
    case "childhood":
      currentText = "Think about your childhood";
      if (delay.expired()) {
        state = "link";
        delay = new Delay(3000);
      }
      break;
    case "link":
      currentText = "Link created";
      break;
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
   if (key == 'j' || key == 'J'){
       head = true;
   }

   if (key == 'y' || key == 'Y'){
       yes = true;
   }

   if (key == 'n' || key == 'N'){
       no = true;
   }
}
```

Please note that, having no idea of what timings you want (or how to order them) I did things kind approximately. You'll have to figure out how to make this work the way you want it to. I think that you'll have every tool to do so at your disposal, now. Also, I'm here if you need more informations.

Have fun!